# Shifting datetime index and using value for function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, finance

I am working on some educational project for myself and now I am trying to create dataframe of financial data where I use function (marketprofile) for each row. Function require DF, start date and end date. I tried to shift index date but it looks like function is trying to take whole index and not just that one line with timestamp. I want to calculate function for previous day.

- function requires start date in format `'2020-04-17 20:00:00'`
- It is working when I select row manually `df[pair]['start'][1]` but then its not calculating for each row obviously...

> ```
> for pair in range(len(pairs_list)):
>     df[pair]['start'] = df[pair].shift(-24, freq='h').index
>     df[pair]['end'] = df[pair].shift(-1, freq='h').index
>     df[pair] = MP(df[pair], df[pair]['start'], df[pair]['end'])
> ```

error I am getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1056         try:
-> 1057             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1058         except (KeyError, ValueError, TypeError):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-524-683e40782404> in <module>
      2     df[pair]['start'] = df[pair].shift(-24, freq='h').index
      3     df[pair]['end'] = df[pair].shift(-1, freq='h').index
----> 4     df[pair] = MP(df[pair], df[pair]['start'], df[pair]['end'])

<ipython-input-161-8cfa0ce6ecf6> in MP(df, start, end)
      1 def MP(df, start, end):
      2     mp = MarketProfile(df, tick_size=0.00001)
----> 3     mp_slice = mp[start: end]
      4     df['initial_balance_low'] = mp_slice.initial_balance()[0]
      5     df['initial_balance_high'] = mp_slice.initial_balance()[1]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/market_profile/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, index)
     19     def __getitem__(self, index):
     20         if isinstance(index, slice):
---> 21             return MarketProfileSlice(self, slice(index.start, index.stop))
     22         else:
     23             raise TypeError("index must be int or slice")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/market_profile/__init__.py in __init__(self, market_profile, _slice)
     34     def __init__(self, market_profile, _slice):
     35         self.mp = market_profile
---> 36         self.ds = self.mp.df[_slice]
     37         self.build_profile()
     38 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2974 
   2975         # Do we have a slicer (on rows)?
-> 2976         indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
   2977         if indexer is not None:
   2978             return self._slice(indexer, axis=0)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in convert_to_index_sliceable(obj, key)
   2356     idx = obj.index
   2357     if isinstance(key, slice):
-> 2358         return idx._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind="getitem")
   2359 
   2360     elif isinstance(key, str):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _convert_slice_indexer(self, key, kind)
   3214         else:
   3215             try:
-> 3216                 indexer = self.slice_indexer(start, stop, step, kind=kind)
   3217             except Exception:
   3218                 if is_index_slice:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   1149 
   1150         try:
-> 1151             return Index.slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind=kind)
   1152         except KeyError:
   1153             # For historical reasons DatetimeIndex by default supports

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   5032         slice(1, 3)
   5033         """
-> 5034         start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
   5035 
   5036         # return a slice

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_locs(self, start, end, step, kind)
   5246         start_slice = None
   5247         if start is not None:
-> 5248             start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, "left", kind)
   5249         if start_slice is None:
   5250             start_slice = 0

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   5162         # we need to look up the label
   5163         try:
-> 5164             slc = self.get_loc(label)
   5165         except KeyError as err:
   5166             try:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1063 
   1064             try:
-> 1065                 stamp = Timestamp(key)
   1066                 if stamp.tzinfo is not None and self.tz is not None:
   1067                     stamp = stamp.tz_convert(self.tz)

pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()

TypeError: Cannot convert input [d
2019-04-01 00:00:00   2019-03-31 00:00:00
2019-04-01 01:00:00   2019-03-31 01:00:00
2019-04-01 02:00:00   2019-03-31 02:00:00
2019-04-01 03:00:00   2019-03-31 03:00:00
2019-04-01 04:00:00   2019-03-31 04:00:00
                              ...        
2020-04-24 17:00:00   2020-04-23 17:00:00
2020-04-24 18:00:00   2020-04-23 18:00:00
2020-04-24 19:00:00   2020-04-23 19:00:00
2020-04-24 20:00:00   2020-04-23 20:00:00
2020-04-24 21:00:00   2020-04-23 21:00:00
Name: start, Length: 6679, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

To show what I want it to do, here is for loop with manualy selected rows:

```
for pair in range(len(pairs_list)):
    df[pair]['start'] = df[pair].shift(-24, freq='h').index
    df[pair]['end'] = df[pair].shift(-1, freq='h').index
    df[pair] = MP(df[pair], df[pair]['start'][1], df[pair]['end'][10])
```

and dataframe looks like this now:

```
Out[526]:
Open    High    Low Close   Volume  time_shift  Day start   end initial_balance_low initial_balance_high    poc value_area_low  value_area_high
d                                                       
2019-04-01 00:00:00 1.12222 1.12253 1.12205 1.12236 6096.2900   1   Mon 2019-03-31 00:00:00 2019-03-31 23:00:00 1.12205 1.12284 1.12464 1.12341 1.12464
2019-04-01 01:00:00 1.12235 1.12284 1.12214 1.12283 9612.3398   1   Mon 2019-03-31 01:00:00 2019-04-01 00:00:00 1.12205 1.12284 1.12464 1.12341 1.12464
2019-04-01 02:00:00 1.12283 1.12297 1.12254 1.12263 9212.0098   1   Mon 2019-03-31 02:00:00 2019-04-01 01:00:00 1.12205 1.12284 1.12464 1.12341 1.12464
2019-04-01 03:00:00 1.12264 1.12333 1.12245 1.12318 8876.4004   1   Mon 2019-03-31 03:00:00 2019-04-01 02:00:00 1.12205 1.12284 1.12464 1.12341 1.12464
2019-04-01 04:00:00 1.12319 1.12340 1.12304 1.12321 6677.4502   1   Mon 2019-03-31 04:00:00 2019-04-01 03:00:00 1.12205 1.12284 1.12464 1.12341 1.12464
```

Problem is that I want to calculate that function for each row with shifted index values as entry and exit dates for function (now it calculate the same values for each row). So at 02:00:00 it will take entry time one hour earlier 01:00:00

This is the function:

```
def MP(df, start, end):
    mp = MarketProfile(df, tick_size=0.00001)
    mp_slice = mp[start: end]
    df['initial_balance_low'] = mp_slice.initial_balance()[0]
    df['initial_balance_high'] = mp_slice.initial_balance()[1]
    df['poc'] = mp_slice.poc_price
    df['value_area_low'] = mp_slice.value_area[0]
    df['value_area_high'] = mp_slice.value_area[1]
    return df
```

Comment: not really clear what you're trying to do, can you post some data?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have updated my question (added example on the bottom) so it hopefully makes more sense now.

Comment: you're getting a type error, what input does your MP function take? maybe post that as well

Comment: I have added function code

Comment: what is mp? an array?

Comment: when I print type(mp) it says: market_profile.MarketProfile

Comment: Are you using the https://pypi.org/project/MarketProfile/ library?

Comment: yes that one. Why?

Comment: to debug, would add some print functions in to make sure you are inputting what you think you are, and make sure you have the correct format for the datetime index, needs to be timestamp i think

Comment: It is strange, because if I run it with manually added timestamps it works just fine MP(df[pair], '2020-04-15 20:00:00', '2020-04-16 20:00:00'), so problem should be with df[pair]['start'] and df[pair]['end'] i guess.

Comment: looks like that is your problem, print df[pair]['start'] and df[pair]['end']

Comment: You can see in dataframe example in question that start and end is giving me correct timestamps(column names are moved to the left). So I can select them and print value through df[pair]['start'][0] and I get Timestamp('2019-03-31 00:00:00')

Comment: are you sure? not sure what df[pair]['start'] is doing, looks like you're assigning some object properties to the column. try to simplify what you are doing then you can find what is going wrong.

Comment: It should shift df by 24 hours and then assign index value to the column. At least I hope. I am new to programming. Thanks for answers anyway